# ORACLE SQL: Builld a REGEXP_SUBSTR in a CASE statement

Tags: oracle

I have the following columns: CODE_LINES AND TABLE_NAME

CODE_LINES - contains the whole code line of code

- from this line extracted just the name of the table (ex. T_CLIENTS ) and created a column TABLE_NAME
- the issue is that my SUBSTR returns the whole line and i would need it to show only the name of the table (ex. T_CLIENTS ) and nothing else after that
- do you guys can help with transforming my SUBSTR in a REGEXP_SUBSTR? 
  Thank you

  ```
  SELECT 
  CASE 
  WHEN INSTR(TRIM(ALLS.CODE_LINES), '.')>1 AND SUBSTR(TRIM(ALLS.CODE_LINES), 1, 6) in ('<FROM>','<INTO>','<RULE>') 
  THEN SUBSTR(TRIM(ALLS.CODE_LINES), INSTR(TRIM(ALLS.CODE_LINES), '.')+1, LENGTH(TRIM(ALLS.CODE_LINES)))
  ELSE SUBSTR(TRIM(ALLS.CODE_LINES), 8, LENGTH(TRIM(ALLS.CODE_LINES))) END AS TABLE_NAME,
  CODE_LINES
  FROM TABLE_A

  CODE_LINES                                                                             TABLE_NAME
  <FROM> X.T_CLIENTS   WHERE TARGET_DATA ...                      T_CLIENTS   WHERE TARGET_DATA ...
  <INTO> Y.T_COSTS   WHERE CLIENT= ...                                   T_COSTS   WHERE CLIENT= ...       
  <FROM> Z.T_FINANCE   WHERE CUSTOMER ...                          T_FINANCE   WHERE CUSTOMER ...   
  <INTO> Q.T_OPERATIONS   WHERE NAME= ...                           T_OPERATIONS   WHERE NAME= ...
  ```

At the moment I tried to build a REGEXP_SUBSTR but only retrieves X.T_CLIENTS. How can i modify it in order to get only T_CLIENTS?

```
    SELECT 
    CASE 
    WHEN INSTR(TRIM(ALLS.CODE_LINES), '.')>1 AND SUBSTR(TRIM(ALLS.CODE_LINES), 1, 6) in ('<FROM>','<INTO>','<RULE>') 
    THEN  REGEXP_SUBSTR(TRIM(ALLS.TEXT),'(\S*)(\s)', 1, 2)
    ELSE SUBSTR(TRIM(ALLS.CODE_LINES), 8, LENGTH(TRIM(ALLS.CODE_LINES))) END AS TABLE_NAME,
    CODE_LINES
    FROM TABLE_A
```

After running this code i get:

```
    TABLE_NAME
    X.T_CLIENTS
    Y.T_COSTS
    Z.T_FINANCE
    Q.T_OPERATIONS
```

The desired output:

```
    TABLE_NAME
    T_CLIENTS
    T_COSTS
    T_FINANCE
    T_OPERATIONS
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show realistic data and the output you're trying to achieve. If a regular expression is appropriate, how far have you got with using one, and what was wrong with your attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More data would be useful, but if I understand correctly you're looking for something like:

```
regexp_replace(code_lines, '^(<[^>]+>\s*)?([^ .]+\.)?([^ ]+)(.*)$', '\3')
```

That creates four groups, via the parentheses. The first group is optional and gives you the `<FROM>` etc. followed by any number of spaces. The second group is optional and gives you anything that isn't a space or a period, but which is followed by a period. The third is any run of characters that aren't spaces. The fourth is whatever is left. You want the third group, which represents the table name in your example.

From a previous question you may also want the schema, which is the second group. With some additional made-up data:

```
select code_lines,
  rtrim(regexp_replace(code_lines, '^(<[^>]+>\s*)?([^ .]+\.)?([^ ]+)(.*)$', '\2'),
    '.') as owner,
  regexp_replace(code_lines, '^(<[^>]+>\s*)?([^ .]+\.)?([^ ]+)(.*)$', '\3')
    as table_name
from table_a;

CODE_LINES                               OWNER                          TABLE_NAME                    
---------------------------------------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
<FROM> X.T_CLIENTS WHERE TARGET_DATA ... X                              T_CLIENTS                     
<INTO> Y.T_COSTS WHERE CLIENT= ...       Y                              T_COSTS                       
<FROM> Z.T_FINANCE WHERE CUSTOMER ...    Z                              T_FINANCE                     
<INTO> Q.T_OPERATIONS WHERE NAME= ...    Q                              T_OPERATIONS                  
<RULE> Q.T_OPERATIONS WHERE NAME= ...    Q                              T_OPERATIONS                  
<FROM> T_FINANCE WHERE CUSTOMER ...                                     T_FINANCE                     
<OTHER> T_FINANCE WHERE CUSTOMER ...                                    T_FINANCE                     
<OTHER> Z.T_FINANCE WHERE CUSTOMER ...   Z                              T_FINANCE                     
T_FINANCE WHERE CUSTOMER ...                                            T_FINANCE                     
Z.T_FINANCE WHERE CUSTOMER ...           Z                              T_FINANCE
```

Or allowing for other whitespace:

```
select code_lines,
  rtrim(regexp_replace(code_lines,
    '^(<[^>]+>[[:space:]]*)?([^[:space:].]+\.)?([[:alnum:]_]+)(.*)$', '\2'), '.')
    as owner,
  regexp_replace(code_lines,
    '^(<[^>]+>[[:space:]]*)?([^[:space:].]+\.)?([[:alnum:]_]+)(.*)$', '\3')
    as table_name
from table_a;
```

which gets the same output.

Of course, trying to parse this kind of thing is likely to throw up edge cases. It won't be happy with some quoted identifiers, for instance, but hopefully you don't have any of those. It will hopefully give you a starting point anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was really helpful and after i tried both queries, it actually works this one - returns a clean row                                             regexp_replace(code_lines,
    '^(<[^>]+>[[:space:]]*)?([^[:space:].]+\.)?([[:alnum:]_]+)(.*)$', '\3')
    as table_name